# EndpointsModel vs ndb.Model

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

So I stumbled on `EndpointsModel` as a means of creating models. When I look online, there is basically no tutorial about it. For people who have used it, what's the advantage? Instead of `ndb.Model` I mean.

Edit:

Also, I tried to mimic the code at [What is the best way to auth, identify and store delicate information about users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527631/what-is-the-best-way-to-auth-identify-and-store-delicate-information-about-user) just to check it out, but my eclipse red-lines it:

```
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Endpoints Proto Datastore API is not an official part of the App Engine SDK, but a library I have been working on.

It is [documented](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/) and I'm happy to come on here and answer your questions. As it turns out, `EndpointsModel` is a [subclass of `ndb.Model`](https://code.google.com/p/endpoints-proto-datastore/source/browse/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py?r=1180a1787e2b138c31a6aa92e52427227b6e62d7#593), so you are getting the best of both worlds:

```
>>> from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel
>>> from google.appengine.ext import ndb
>>> EndpointsModel.__bases__ == (ndb.Model,)
True
```

As mentioned on the docs landing page, the advantage is that the library:

> ...allows existing model classes to be used with Google Cloud
>   Endpoints. By extending the functionality provided by `ndb.Model` class
>   and the `endpoints` library, this library allows you to directly
>   interact with model entities in your API methods rather than ProtoRPC
>   requests.

We have also given a [talk](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/150149336/) on using the library. In it, we explicitly mention that you'll need to add the [`endpoints_proto_datastore` library](https://code.google.com/p/endpoints-proto-datastore/downloads/detail?name=endpoints_proto_datastore.zip) to your application.

```
$ cd path/to/your/application/code
$ wget https://endpoints-proto-datastore.googlecode.com/files/endpoints_proto_datastore.zip
$ unqip -q endpoints_proto_datastore.zip
```